# select a specific array index in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

i entered the input **1,0,1,1** through HTML form but its show error

Undefined offset: 1 in $data[1]==1.
Match not found

can anyone help how can i do it ....??

```
<?php
                    $data=$_REQUEST['data'];
                    $length=count($data);
                    for($a=0;$a<$length;$a++)
                    {
                        echo $data[$a]."&nbsp;";
                        if ($data[1]==1)
                          {
                          echo "Match found";
                          }
                        else
                          {
                          echo "Match not found";
                          }
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: are you submitting a array or string "1,0,1,1". If string then use explode(',',$data)

Comment: i am jst inserting 1,0,1,1 in the form field and submitting to the php code

Comment: I think it should be `if($data[$a] == 1) ...` .Otherwise you have to also check the `$length` it should be greater than 1.

Comment: i wanted to check if the first element of the array is equal to 1 it should print the message

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems that you actually need

```php
if ($data[$a]==1)
```

instead of

```php
if ($data[1]==1)
```

The second thing is that if offset `1` is undefined, then your array actually contains less then 2 elements (firs is offset 0, second should be 1). I bet that your data array looks something like

```php
$data = array(
   [0] => '1,0,1,1'
)
```

so you need to split it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try and print out your array, with print_r($arrayName), and check that the indexes are as you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data=$_REQUEST['data'];
$data = explode(',',$data);
$length=sizeof($data);
for($a=0;$a<$length;$a++)
{
echo $data[$a]."&nbsp;";
if ($data[0]==1)
{
echo "Match found";
}
else
{
echo "Match not found";
}
}
?>
```

Explode will convert your string into an array, then you can use `$data[$a]`